# Buttons don't expand

Tags: python, tkinter

I currently have this code and it supposed to expand the buttons to fill in the window but it doesn't work. I did checked and follow exactly all the step but it did not work in this for some reasons

my code:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import N, S, E, W
#from numpy import transpose

grid_size = 3
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry(str(grid_size*70)+'x'+str(grid_size*70))
root.title("Tic Tac Toe")
tk.Grid.rowconfigure(root, 0, weight= 1)
tk.Grid.columnconfigure(root, 0, weight= 1)
frame = tk.Frame(root)
frame.grid(row= 0, column= 0, sticky=N+S+E+W)
Flip = True

class Game():
    def __init__(self, X, Y):
        self.team = ' '
        tk.Grid.rowconfigure(frame, X, weight= 1)
        tk.Grid.columnconfigure(frame, Y, weight= 1)
        self.button = tk.Button(
            frame,
            text= ' ', 
            fg= 'white',
            font= ('Arial', 20), 
            command= self.Set_Var
            )
        self.button.grid(row= X, column= Y, sticky= N+S+E+W)

    def Set_Var(self):
        global Flip
        if self.team == ' ':
            if Flip:
                self.button.configure(text= 'X', bg= 'lightblue')
                self.team = 'X'
                Flip = False
            else:
                self.button.configure(text= 'O', bg= 'lightgreen')
                self.team = 'O'
                Flip = True
        
for I in range(grid_size):
    for J in range(grid_size): Game(I,J)

frame.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: It is because you called `frame.pack()` and I wonder why you call it because `frame.grid(...)` has been called already.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `grid` it helps to use different parts of the area. When you use the `pack` method it organizes the blocks in the parent widget. You have called `.grid()` properly, but you have called the `.pack()` method at the end which is wrong. Omit the line `frame.pack()`.

So the final code looks like this:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import N, S, E, W
#from numpy import transpose

grid_size = 3
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry(str(grid_size*70)+'x'+str(grid_size*70))
root.title("Tic Tac Toe")
tk.Grid.rowconfigure(root, 0, weight= 1)
tk.Grid.columnconfigure(root, 0, weight= 1)
frame = tk.Frame(root)
frame.grid(row= 0, column= 0, sticky=N+S+E+W)
Flip = True

class Game():
    def __init__(self, X, Y):
        self.team = ' '
        tk.Grid.rowconfigure(frame, X, weight= 1)
        tk.Grid.columnconfigure(frame, Y, weight= 1)
        self.button = tk.Button(
            frame,
            text= ' ', 
            fg= 'white',
            font= ('Arial', 20), 
            command= self.Set_Var
            )
        self.button.grid(row= X, column= Y, sticky= N+S+E+W)

    def Set_Var(self):
        global Flip
        if self.team == ' ':
            if Flip:
                self.button.configure(text= 'X', bg= 'lightblue')
                self.team = 'X'
                Flip = False
            else:
                self.button.configure(text= 'O', bg= 'lightgreen')
                self.team = 'O'
                Flip = True
        
for I in range(grid_size):
    for J in range(grid_size): Game(I,J)

root.mainloop()
```

And the GUI looks like this:

[image: tic tac toe game gui]